# Saving a file in an internal directory proper to an Android library

Tags: java, android, jar, libraries

I'm working on an Android library that's meant to be used by multiple applications. The library needs to save data to a file that can be accessed by any of these applications.

Let's say I have two applications that use this library:

- package com.example.app1
- package com.example.app2

And that my library is under

- package com.library.sdk

When the library running under app1 tries to save a file to internal storage, it is saved under com.example.app1. So if app2 wants to get access to that file, it needs to look under com.example.app1 using a ContentProvider, for example. The problem is that if app1 is uninstalled, the data saved in the file also vanishes.

Is there no way to let the library save the file to its own internal storage (i.e. under com.library.sdk)? I tried, but seem to get access violations. But shouldn't this be possible given that the library is it's own packaged project/jar?

Comment: A library is not an app, but rather part of an app (or in your case, part of two apps). The two apps share code, but they're ultimately separate entities running in separate sandboxes. You can either duplicate the data, or create a third app (without ui) which acts solely as a content provider to both your apps.

Comment: or store the file in a common folder on external storage, I suppose

Comment: Yep, or that, but than the data is publicly accessible to any other app, and can also be tampered with or deleted.